# Different results during Debug and Run configurations of JDBC-SQLite app

Tags: java, debugging, sqlite

/* Question answered */

Hi, I am using Eclipse 3.6.1 (Helios) and I work with SQLite database through JDBC interface. The problem is that I'm getting different result under Debug and Run modes. Here is the test case:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String db_name = /* path to some SQLite database */;
    try {
        // If we using ch-werner SQLite Java Wrapper/JDBC Driver
        Class.forName("SQLite.JDBCDriver");

        // If we using Xerial or Zentus impl.
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + db_name);
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs; 
        try {
            rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sites;");
            boolean flag = rs.isBeforeFirst(); // Breakpoint here
            System.out.println(flag);
            if (flag) rs.next();
            System.out.println(rs.getObject(1));
        } finally {
            statement.close();
            con.close();
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I tried JDK 1.6.0, 1.6.0_23, JRE 1.6.0; 3 implementations of JDBC-SQLite: [ch-werner SQLite Java Wrapper/JDBC Driver](http://www.ch-werner.de/javasqlite/) (r2011-01-06), [Zentus SQLiteJDBC](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) (0.5.6) and [Xerial SQLite JDBC Driver](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC) (which is extended Zentus, tried 3.6.20 and 3.7.2) for different SQLite test databases.

If I run this under Run configuration, it works fine (prints `true` and desired object), but when I try step-by-step debugging (using breakpoint, followed by Step Over's), it always prints false and `getObject` fails for different reasons (`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 1` under ch-werner impl, and `java.lang.IllegalStateException: SQLite JDBC: inconsistent internal state` under two others). There is no JVM arguments set, just code from scratch. I failed to reprofuce this bug under NetBeans 6.9.

Am I doing something wrong or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you use the debug configuration, but just hit "go" (or whatever Netbeans uses) instead of stepping over each line one by one?

My *guess* is that you've got a watch which is evaluating some method with side-effects (e.g. `rs.next()`) and screwing up the state of the application as you step over lines.

Comment: Your guess is totally correct, I'm sorry for being such a dumb :) I'l accept your answer as soon, as I will be allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

```
int getX(){
    y++;
    return x;
}
```

If you were to put a watch on getX() after every breakpoint the debugger will call getX() and y would increment by 1. And your programm would have a different behaviour from the run mode.