# Return Statement and Break Not Working in "While Loop"

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

I am writing a short algorithm in Java using Netbeans.

The problem I am having is that the code is ignoring the return statement in a while loop. I also tried a break statement, and it ignores that as well.

However, the strange part about the entire thing is that when I run the program with breakpoints, it stops when it is supposed to (when it sees a certain value). If I run it without breakpoints, it runs past that point.

Here is a bit of the code:

```
    while (!openList.isEmpty()) {
        // 1. Remove the best node from OPEN, call it current
        int bestValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (BestFirstNode inOpen : openList) {
                if ((inOpen.x == current.x) && (inOpen.y == current.y)) {
                    //skip this node
                }
                // 2.If one of the values in openList is the goal state, return the goal value
                if (inOpen.value < bestValue) {
                    if (inOpen.value == goal) {
                       System.out.println("GOAL!");
                       openList.clear();
                       return goal;
                    }
                    //else sent thevalue if the new current nodes
                    bestValue = inOpen.value;
                    current = inOpen;

                    //set the new x and y values that will be used to check
                    //for successors
                    x = inOpen.x;
                    y = inOpen.y;
                }
            }

        //print the current node and its coordinates
        System.out.println("Current: " + current.value);
        System.out.println("x: " + current.x + " y: " + current.y + "\n-------------");

        //remove current from the openList so it can't be used again
        openList.remove(current);

        //3. Create current's successors.
        Set<BestFirstNode> successors = new HashSet();
        int min = 0;
        int max = 2;

        //get the top successor
        if ((x <= max) && (x >= min) && (y - 1 <= max) && (y - 1 >= min)) {
            successors.add(grid[x][y - 1]);
        }

        //get the bottom successor
        if (x <= max && x >= min && y + 1 <= max && y + 1 >= min) {
            successors.add(grid[x][y + 1]);
        }

        //get the left successor
        if (x - 1 <= max && x - 1 >= min && y <= max && y >= min) {
            successors.add(grid[x - 1][y]);
        }

        //get the right successor
        if (x + 1 <= max && x + 1 >= min && y <= max && y >= min) {
            successors.add(grid[x + 1][y]);
        }

        //remove the parent node from the successors list
        Set<BestFirstNode> successorsFinal = new HashSet<>();
        for (BestFirstNode successor : successors) {
            if (successor != current.parent) {
                successorsFinal.add(successor);
            }
        }

        //4. Evaluate each successor, add it to OPEN, and record its parent.
        for (BestFirstNode successor : successorsFinal) {
            openList.add(successor);
            successor.parent = current;
        }
    }
```

I read a few other posts regarding similar issues. Reading one post ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756474/different-results-during-debug-and-run-configurations-of-jdbc-sqlite-app)) led me to try running the the debugger without breakpoints. Without them, I get the same issue, but I don't fully understand the answer. I also tried clearing the list so the while condition would not be valid, but it still keeps going.

So, I suppose my question is two-fold:
How can the code completely ignore a break or a return statement? And how can you get one result using breakpoints and another without them?

Edit: I added the full while loop for clarity

Comment: Observe your variables with debugging, you will find the result.

Comment: @Rugal I'm not sure I understand how that will help. When I'm debugging, I get the expected result.

Comment: Where does your `inOpen` Object come from? If you are basically iterating over your `openList` you might be better suited for that purpose with a for-each-loop. If not, watch your `inOpen.value` variable while debugging. Does your code even pass the second if-query?

Comment: @MadMatts Yes, inOpen is just being used to iterate over openList. I added the full while loop for clarity.

Comment: try to initialize the `bestvalue` variable outside of your while loop, because you're overriding your stored value at the beginning of each loop run. So simply put  `int bestValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;` above your while loop. And try again.

Answer (score 0):

Is `openList` being written to/changed by another thread? 
Perhaps it isn't a thread safe list being modified by another thread than the one with your while-loop? 
Or which thread adds the goal to the list?

Answer (score 0):

It's immposible for your code to run after a return statement. After a return Statement the interpreter exits the Method and I can prove this to you.

Do the following test add a System.out.printl before and after the return statement no matter if you run your code with or without breakpoints you will get the same result regarding the return statement.
**EDIT:** *I'm not sure if this test is possible. I can't remmember if unreachable code is markes as a warning or an error.*

Same goes for break Statements, after a break statement the loop is exited. But as you use multiple loops inside eachother it would be confusing to identify which loop you are exiting.

A programm can change it's behaviour inside the debug mode if you have watches. If the Method you have the watch on changes something than you are going to have a different behaviour.

Example:

```
int getX(){
    y++;
    return x;
}
```

If you were to put a watch on getX() after every breakpoint the debugger will call getX() and y would increment by 1. And your programm would have a different behaviour from the run mode.

Conclusion:

1. A programm will never ignore a return or a break statement, please prove me wrong.
2. Breakpoints refresh your Watches, Watches call the Methods they are watching. If those methods change values, than you are going to have a different behaviour.